# Creating multipule tables for sql db (a-z tables)

Tags: android, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I have been trying to creat a multi table DB using a for loop. the db is for bulding a game with words and their translation in another language for studing English but, that's why I need 26 tables(a table for a letter, A-Z)
that's why I thought that the best way of doing so is inside a loop.
I have been trying to add a loop to my DBHelper that extends SQLiteOpenHelper and I don't know why, it doesn't let me do it. it tried doing something like:

```
private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
char c = 'A';
    String[] tableT, DATABASE_TABLE;
    for (int i = 0; i<26; i++){
        DATABASE_TABLE[i] = "" + c;
        tableT[i] ="CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0] + " (" +
            KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            KEY_WORDS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_TRANSLATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_TURNLEFT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
            KEY_ISKNOWN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                            KEY_TOLEARN + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
                     c++;
    }
```

}
eclips keeps red flaggin the semicolon in te end of "DATABASE_TABLE" with the error:

```
Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token
```

does someone know why? is there a way to do the loop outside this class and access it somehow?

Comment: Excuse me.  Why do you need 26 tables, one for each word?  You should be able to do this just fine with one table.  At least one problem, by the way, is the `NUT NULL` in the last line.

Comment: I need A-Z tables, not table for each word. and thanks for noticing th NUT NULL

Comment: You don't need a table for each letter.  One table for all of them should be fine.

Comment: How can I use only one tabe? I want to be able to easly get to words in a specific letter. If ill use one table, it'll be harder to know where are the words from each letter.

Comment: Add a column that specifies the letter and put an index on the column.  Or partition it by the first letter of the word.

Answer (score 0):

If I don´t misunderstood You, You are trying do create every table with different names. But You are creating the tables with the same name:

```
     DATABASE_TABLE[i] = "" + c;
```

will everytime be with table name "A". Also, You set always only table nr. 0 from the Array here:

```
     tableT[i] ="CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[0]
```

Your loop should look like this:

```
           char c = 'A';
String[] tableT, DATABASE_TABLE;
for (int i = 0; i<26; i++){
    DATABASE_TABLE[i] = c +"_"+i;
    tableT[i] ="CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE[i] + " (" +
        KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        KEY_WORDS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
        KEY_TRANSLATION + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
        KEY_TURNLEFT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
        KEY_ISKNOWN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                        KEY_TOLEARN + " TEXT NUT NULL);";
}
```

This should give table names like A_1, A_2 etc.

And the error that eclipse is shown, must be anywhere in Your code where You have forgotten to set a claim {, but this is not postet. What do You mean with "eclips keeps red flaggin the semicolon in te end of "table" with the error"? where is the word "table"?

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear. anyway my intantion is to get A-Z tables, but you are right I forgot to modify c, and my problem is that I know how to create the loop +/-, but for some reason, when I'm in the DBHelper class, it desn't let me write the code as usual. can it be because of the fact the the class extends SQLiteOpenHelper?.